# Laravel AWS SES mails not received

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, laravel-vapor

The issue I have with AWS SES is that on the password reset page (for example) after I send the request I get a successfully sent mail response, but I don't receive that email in my inbox.

[image: Success message]

Since this is my first time working with AWS at all, I guess it is some AWS configuration setup issue.

So, I have verified my email at the AWS console and they have moved me out of the sandbox. I have implemented the AWS-SDK package in my laravel app, and in my .env I have this.

**ENV**

```
MAIL_MAILER=ses
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="my_iam_aws_access_key"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="my_iam_aws_secret_access_key"
```

In my laravel vapor dashboard environment, I have only fields for `MAIL_FROM_NAME` and `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`
Also, I have included the contract "CanResetPassword" to my User model.

Also, there are not any errors in the logs, in vapor-ui, or in the AWS console.

Are there any more suggestions on what could I check or do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Check if your SES account is in sandbox mode, if it is you can only send emails to verified domains or addresses

Comment: @apokryfos Ty for the answer. No, I am not in the sandbox. My request was granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AWS SES .Try this one in .env file
MAIL_HOST come from SES dasboard/section in which region you have implemented SES.Also along to create smtp you have to create IAM User with fullAwsSESAccess permission.

```
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
```

[image]

Comment: I have that access already, will try this setup though. Thank you! Will reach back with the feedback :D

Comment: Mails are still not received in the inbox, but as I can see I have used some daily quota of the mails. Seems like the setup is good, I am just not sure why I can't see them.

Comment: Look this reference document to implement ses in Laravel.

https://mattkomarnicki.com/articles/php-sending-e-mail-in-laravel-using-smtp-and-amazon-ses

then follow your steps with this document.

I hope this will help you.